# Eclipse BIRT report designer to XSL

Tags: eclipse, birt

Is there a possible means to convert the report designer file (xml) generated in Eclipse BIRT
to XSL ?

Comment: XSL (Extensible Stylesheet Language)

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?  The underlying question/need is not clear.

Comment: What i want to do is that i design the report using Eclipse BIRT tool.Since the designer file generated is basically an xml-based file i was looking for a possible alternative to convert the designer file into a XSLfile and then use FOP to render it to PDF. I can directly convert to pdf from BIRT but my requirement is that i need to store this designer file as XSLT